# WCF Client Certificate purpose?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, certificate, duplex

We have some WCF duplex services using net/tcp that we use for events in some of the software we create. These services currently have a service certificate set, and a client certificate, that we build into our client library, and then we use Username/Password authentication on top of this, to ensure who the user is. And this all works great.

But i have a question regarding the client certificate, because i have been reading around on MSDN, but had a hard time finding the answer, but now i would like a straight answer.

Does the client certificate have any impact on the encryption (security) of the messages, or is it only to help identification?